# javascript computation yield different result

Tags: javascript

I want to get the same value with the result from the excel sheet but the computations yield a different result , anyone has an idea why ? I cant get the -13 percent from the excel?

I think my e Nullish Coalescing Operator is correct also.

#excel

[image]

#ts code

```
this.dealDispositionFormFields.salePrice = 10000000
this.dealDispositionFormFields.brokerCommission = 125000
this.dealDispositionFormFields.transactionCosts = 50000
this.dealDispositionFormFields.netBookValue = 11250000


  calc() {
    this.netProceeds = (this.dealDispositionFormFields.salePrice ?? 0) - (this.dealDispositionFormFields.brokerCommission ?? 0) - (this.dealDispositionFormFields.transactionCosts ?? 0);
    this.netSaleGainLossRate = (this.netProceeds ?? 0) - (this.dealDispositionFormFields.netBookValue ?? 0);
    this.netSaleGainLossPercentage = (this.netSaleGainLossRate ?? 0)/(this.dealDispositionFormFields.netBookValue ?? 0);
  }
```

#current result
[image]

Comment: The values look the same to me. Which ones are you referring to?

Comment: times 100, decimal to percentage? 1/2 = .5 ... x100 = 50%

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: _I cant get the -13 percent from the excel?_ `-00.13` is `-13%`. You just need to format it differently.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp In excel the result is -13% but in my js code the result is different even using the same formula

Comment: what is the name of thae formal @JohnnyMopp ? that would convert -00.13 to - 13%?

Comment: -00.13 is the same thing as -13%...

Comment: what is the specific name of the convertion Sir ? so that I will know

Comment: do you mean decimal to percentage right ?

Comment: this.netSaleGainLossPercentage = Math.floor(this.netSaleGainLossPercentage * 100) + '%'`

Comment: Also another question Sir , why is that on excel the B10-B7 does not yield a negative answer?

Comment: It is negative. Excel represents negative money values by putting them in parentheses `( )`.